# Bootstrap - Full Width Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap. In this app, I have a list of items that I can reorder. Currently, my list looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<ul id="choices" class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
  </li>

  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
  </li>

  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make this list such that each item fills the entire width of the entire space. In other words, I want it to looks like this:

div

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                           |
| = _____________________________________________________________________ x |
| = _____________________________________________________________________ x |
| = _____________________________________________________________________ x |
|                                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

At the moment, when I do this, I get the `input` field on a different line and I can't get each list item to fill the available space. What am I missing?

Comment: can you upload your sample project somewhere to make tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-12">
<ul id="choices" class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-reorder fa-fw"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-reorder fa-fw"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-reorder fa-fw"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw"></i></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

you can add icons to each side of an input with bootstrap

take a look at this:

[bootstrap input addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic)

see following for an example with font awesome icons (go to bootstrap 3 examples)

[font awesome examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)

Comment: Answer does not fully satisfy the question.

Comment: What is missing then? Added a code snippet to prove this solution works

Comment: Sad that it needs to have code to copy to be considered a good answer... All information was there.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `float` with an explicit `width` on your icon, and adding `overflow:hidden` to the input [codepen](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/pbWgWk)

HTML

```
<ul id="choices" class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-reorder left"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle right"></i>
    <div class="middle"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}

.middle {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that each list item does not take up the entire width of the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootrstrap inline forms

```
<li class="form-inline">     
   <div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: why would you need a `<form>` element just for a class?

Comment: @IE5Master you right, edited. I just answered pretty fast :)

Answer (score -1):

try col-xs-12 and width attribute in styles